# Do you get full experience from kills to lower level monsters in Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight

Is the level difference between my character and the enemies in Torchlight important? Do I earn the same amount of experience independent of the level difference?

In Diablo 2 you can earn only a small percentage of the actual experience if the level difference is too high. Is this the same in Torchlight?

I'm currently level 58 and fighting level 68 enemies and I have the feeling that I only earn experience from champions but not from normal monsters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember well experience gained depends on monster levels and does not scale with your level. You are right, the experience that you get from killing mini-bosses is very high compared to that acquired from killing normal monsters.

There is also a type of fish that increase your XP gain by 20% for 300 seconds. Remember to eat one of that before big fights.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know this fish, but unfortunately I only have one ;) I'm still saving it until a very big fight ;)

Comment: @Roflcoptr, I guess you have the same problem as me: I like to save items until I know I really really need to use them! So... things like this happen: http://www.awkwardzombie.com/index.php?page=0&comic=072709

Comment: @denilson hehe! I also do it, conserve, conserve, conserve... until the ending credits.

Comment: Also, http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=176